# Changing number format in ToC and in cross references independently

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, numbering

I am trying tu customize how the numbering format of sections, subsections, etc. in the table of contents using the `book` class. Basically, the problem is that changing any style with `\renewcommand` changes it everywhere, and I want to change it for the table of contents independently from the style for the cross references.

I know the `titlesec` package, but it only changes the style of the actual headers, and not the cross references.

More precisely, my MWE is the following.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}.\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\roman{chapter}.\arabic{paragraph}.}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section one}\label{sec:one}
\subsection{Subsection A}\label{subsec:one.a}

\subsection{Subsection B}

\section{Section two}
Same as Section~\ref{sec:one}.

\section{Section three}
\subsection{Subsection A}
Same as Subsection~\ref{subsec:one.a}.

\end{document}
```

It produces the table of contents

[image]

and the body of the book

[image]

Now, I am happy with how the body looks, but I would like, for example, to drop the roman "I" in front of the section and subsection numbers in the table of contents, and NOT in the cross references.

I would appreciate all your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing out the toc-entry LaTeX sets `\label` to `\@gobble`. So you could test for it:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\ifx\label\@gobble\else\thechapter.\fi\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\ifx\label\@gobble\else\thechapter.\fi\arabic{section}.\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\roman{chapter}.\arabic{paragraph}.}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section one}\label{sec:one}
\subsection{Subsection A}\label{subsec:one.a}

\subsection{Subsection B}

\section{Section two}
Same as Section~\ref{sec:one}.

\section{Section three}
\subsection{Subsection A}
Same as Subsection~\ref{subsec:one.a}.

\end{document}
```